# Aggregate pageviews on paths with variable parameters

Tags: google-analytics, single-page-application, google-tag-manager

We are using Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics to track page views and user behaviour in a Single Page Application.

The web application has several sections designed to be beneath a specific project URL, so we have this kind of application routing:

```
/projects/{projectId}/section1
/projects/{projectId}/section2
/projects/{projectId}/section3
```

So currently our tracking works like this:

```
/projects/abc/section1: 3 pageviews
/projects/xyz/section1: 7 pageviews

/projects/abc/section2: 10 pageviews
/projects/xyz/section2: 10 pageviews

/projects/abc/section3: 3 pageviews
/projects/xyz/section3: 2 pageviews
```

We now want to also gather aggregated per-section data, such as:

```
/section1: 10 page views
/section2: 20 page views
/section3: 5 page views
```

Is there any suggested way to do so using GTM or any Analytics settings that helps us aggregating these information?

Also we want to do this without having to modify the web application (we can modify the application but we prefer it to be kept as much agnostic as possible in regards of analytics tracking).

Comment: You could create a custom dimension with the section as value. Or if you do not want to change anything, you could do your reporting in Data Studio, and create a custom field based on the "section" segment of your urls. In both cases I am not 100% convinced that this is a programming question within the scope of SO.

Comment: I've read something about custom dimension, that could be the case, is that something you control in the dataLayer push from GTM or is it something to be entirely defined in the GA dashboard?. 
Regarding this being in topic of SO I partially agree with you but sadly I couldn't find another place where these kind of questions are in topic so here I am asking the SO community :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use Universal Analytics (and not the new Google Analytics for Apps and Web), you could create a hit based custom dimension, which would allow for a custom report with hit based metrics (such as number of pageviews - "hit based" means this is tracked per request, "session based" would store only the last value in a session). This takes some preparations in Google Analytics, but implementation-wise it can be done in the GTM interface without touching the page code (provided that page tracking is already set up correctly for your SPA).

First go the GA admin interface, to the middle column with the property settings (custom dimension are created at property level) and search for "custom definitions". Expand, click "custom dimensions", click new. Enter a name, e.g, "Sections", select "hit-based" for the scope and make sure the "active" checkbox is checked. Click "save". In the overview you will see that custom dimensions have a numeric index, if this your first custom dimension the index will be "1".

Now, go to Google Tag Manager. Enable the built-in "page path" variable. Go to custom variables, click "new", and select "custom Javascript" as type. Write some custom script to return the last segment of your path. Custom Javascript variables take the form of an anonymous function, so this could look like this:

```
function() {
    return {{Page Path}}.split("/").pop();
}
```

`{{Page Path}}` is the built-in page (the url without protocol, hostname and parameters), the `split("/")` splits it along the delimiter and stores the value in an array, and the `pop()` returns the last element of the array, so this will always give you the bit that contains the section.

Now go to your Google Analytics tag (either the settings tag, if you want this to be send on all hits, or your pageview tags, if you want this only in pageviews; in the latter case you will e.g. be not able to filter your event reports by section). In the "custom dimensions" setting (under "more settings" in the pageview tag) click "add custom dimension". In the index field enter the numeric index for the dimension you have created in GA. In the value field, enter your "section" variable ({{Section}}, GTM variables are denoted by double curly brackets in the interface). Save, publish, wait a few hours, create a custom report with the custom dimension as primary dimension (custom dimensions do not show up in standard reports), add all hit-based metrics you want (e.h. page views) and you should be good to go.

Comment: I'll try this in a few hours and get back with a feedback but it seems pretty straighforward, thanks!

Comment: It might take a day (documentation says 24 hours, but usually it's faster) before custom dimensions actually show up in GA (but you will see them being sent in the network tab, in the tag properties in the GTM preview pane or in the GA debugger).